# combine_first doesn't seems to have any affect dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table with multiple rows, which should be grouped on the number in 1st column. In other columns there is data which I need to combine to single row.

I tried combine_first function, but don't understand why it's not working.

Im trying to make this:

```
df6=pd.DataFrame({'JobNumber':[647,817,915], 'Column6':['KT35','KT35','KT35'],'Column7':[1, 4, 1],
                 'Column8':[1.5, 1.7 ,1], 'Column9':[0,1,2.03]})
```

from this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'JobNumber':[647,647,817,817,817, 915,915,915],'Column6':['KT35','KT35','KT35','KT35','KT35','KT35','KT35','KT35'],
                 'Column7':[0, 1, 0, 0 , 4, 1, 0, 0],'Column8':[1.5, 0 ,0 ,1.7,0,0,0,1], 'Column9':[0,0,1,0,0,0,2.03,0]})
```

In other words I'm trying to create a line for each JobNumber with all data in one row.

I' came up with this code:

```
df2 = pd.read_excel(file.xlsx)
df2.columns=['JobNumber','Column6','Column7','Column8','Column9']

df3 = df2.loc[[0],:]
for i in range(len(df2.JobNumber)):
  JobNum = df2.iloc[i, 0]
  if df2.iloc[i,0] == df2.iloc[i-1, 0]:
      df3.loc[df3.JobNumber == JobNum,:] = df3.loc[df3.JobNumber == JobNum,:].combine_first(df2.iloc[[i],:])
  else:
      df3.append(df2.iloc[i,:])
```

But combine_first line doesn't seem to work. df3.append(**) also don't work
I can't understand what is wrong with my code :/ It doesn't show any error, it just looks like my loop has no effect on df3, because when i print it out it's only 1 row in it, the one i assign to it before

Comment: Welcome to stack. So that you get help faster, please give sample data and desired output in a non image format. Try concisely explain what you really want in words. Your code may be good but people dont read code partly because they may have different styles of writing codes and partly because often the error is in the code of the person seeking help.

Comment: @wwnde Hi, I added an example of source file and edited the post to make it more explicit. What else I should add to it?

Comment: Did either of these solutions answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.where(df.ne(0)).groupby(['JobNumber','Column6'],as_index=False).first().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   JobNumber Column6  Column7  Column8  Column9
0        647    KT35      1.0      1.5     0.00
1        817    KT35      4.0      1.7     1.00
2        915    KT35      1.0      1.0     2.03
```

Old answer:

I am not sure the extent of this, but if it alternates between these two columns like in the example provided, the code below should work.

```
df['col8'] = df['col8'].shift()
df = df.dropna(subset=['col8'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would fill the blanks `''` with `NaN`

```
df.replace('', np.nan)
```

I would the `.ffill()` and `bfill()` at the same time

Then drop `.duplicates()`

See mock data and the solution below. All I have done is to chain the methods above together

**Data**

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Column5':[647,647,817,817],'Column6':['KT35','KT35','KT35','KT35'],'Column7':['',1,'',1],'Column8':[1.5,'',2,''], 'Column9':['','','','']})
print(df)


    Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9
0      647    KT35             1.5        
1      647    KT35       1                
2      817    KT35               2        
3      817    KT35       1     

df=df.replace('', np.nan).ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates(keep='first')
print(df)


   Column5 Column6  Column7  Column8  Column9
0      647    KT35      1.0      1.5      NaN
2      817    KT35      1.0      2.0      NaN
```